# How to use requestAnimationFrame with a TypeScript object?

Tags: typescript, this, requestanimationframe

I have an object that i want to do drawing on a canvas. It will use `requestAnimationFrame` to start a game loop:

**Contoso.ts**

```
class Contoso
{
   //private ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

   Initialize(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
      //this.ctx = ctx;
      Render();
   }

   Render() {
      //...snip doing any actual drawing for the purpose of this question
      requestAnimationFrame(this.Render);
   }
}
```

**app.ts**

```
var contoso: Contoso;

contoso = new Contoso();
contoso.Initialize(canvas);
```

The first time someone calls `Initialize`, the `requestAnimationFrame` manages to correctly call `Render`.

The second time `requestAnimationFrame` calls `Render`, the `this.Render` is `undefined` and it crashes.

It's almost as though the object was destroyed after the initial call to `Initialize`.

What is going on?

Comment: A video on how to maintain `this` : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You've lost `this` context. Two possible fixes:

```
class Contoso
{
   /* ... */

   // Use () => syntax so Render always gets 'this' context
   // from the class instance
   Render = () => {
      //...snip doing any actual drawing for the purpose of this question
      requestAnimationFrame(this.Render);
   }
}
```

The alternate fix is probably slightly clearer, but has the downside of making a lot more allocations (you probably don't want to allocate 1 closure per frame!)

```
   Render() {
      //...snip doing any actual drawing for the purpose of this question
      requestAnimationFrame(() => this.Render);
   }
```

Comment: At least I know I'm not crazy - people have had this problem before me. On the other hand, the fixed versions smell enough that I'm probably not supposed to have a class maintain the render loop. I am probably supposed to have global variables invoke the a Render method on that global variable

Comment: @Ryan: First suggestion (i.e. Render = () => { ... }) works nicely. Thanks.

Comment: is there any need of cancelling the animation frame for the performance? if yes then please let me know how can I do it?

Answer (score 8):

Use arrow syntax (lambda):

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => this.Render());
```

Comment: Yeah for some reason this does not work. The Render function does not even get called.

Answer (score 4):

The best approach I've found.

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.Render.bind(this));
```

`.bind(this)` creates a new function that has its `this` keyword set to the provided value.

### Bonus Reading

- [MDN: bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: using `bind` is dangerous: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/bind.html

Comment: Can you expand on `bind`'s dangers, @gregmatys? The page you linked to doesn't exist at that URL any more, and a search on the site didn't (quickly) show up anything explicitly arising against binding class methods. When writing class-based React code in JavaScript, the `this.fn = this.fn.bind(this)` pattern is very common. I assume many people will encounter problems like this moving to TypeScript, so more explanation here would help.

Comment: https://hamednourhani.gitbooks.io/typescript-book/docs/tips/bind.html

Answer (score 2):

On Firefox 49.0.1 I've got an error message using Ryan Cavanaugh solution.

> SyntaxError: bad method definition

for the line :

> Render = ()=> {

The work around I've found looks like this :

```
class Test{

    constructor(){

        this.Render = ()=> {
            requestAnimationFrame( this.Render );
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: Try it with `Render = () => {` instead of `this.Render = () => {`. To be clear, I am referring to @Ryan's code, outside of a constructor.